# How I can fetch images from JSON object and pass it to form-data

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, axios

Below you can see the json object It has image field.I want to grab the image from that field and pass it to form-data and afterwards I want to pass that form-data to carry out post request via Axios.The post request accept multipart/form-data as a header and a token for authentication and form-data as data .

```
 {
"id": 4,
"title": "myProduct ",
"description": "",
"price": "64/Kg",
"subcode": "subcode1",
"status": "active",
"user_id": 4,
"category_id": 1,
"slug": "anything",
"created_at": "2019-01-03 20:30",
"updated_at": "2019-06-11 11:49",
"gst": 5,
"vendor_id": 1,
"rank": null,
"fresh": 0,
"delivery_id": 1,
"buffer_time": 12,
"discount": null,
"subscribed": null,
"subcategory_id": null,
"commission": null,
"images": [
{
"id": 137,
"src": "https://anything/1547719669239.jpeg",
"product_id": 4
}
]
}
```

This is how i have to make request i am getting error status 422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY please look into it

curl -i -X POST 
-H "X-Token: USER_TOKEN" 
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "image[attachment]=@/absolute/path/to/image.jpg" 
-F "type=image/jpeg" 
https://localhost:3000/anything/images

Code that I  tried  is below

```
   app.post("/images",async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image[attachment]",items[4].images[0].src,{type:"image/jpeg"});
            const headers = {
                "Content-Type" :"multipart/form-data",
            }
            
            let resp = await axios.post(" https://localhost:3000/anything/images",formData,{
                headers:headers,
                params:{
                    token:"mytoken"
                },
            })
            console.log(resp.status);
            return;
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        
        res.send("Outside"

); })
```

Comment: Can you please let us know if you have tried anything yet? If yes, then please post the code as well.

Comment: till now nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by first downloading the image to my local system and passing it like
data.append('image[attachment]', fs.createReadStream('/home/images/riceBasm.jpeg'));

As the request work with postman so I checked the code section of postman and I found this piece of code over there . So do check the postman code section if you get stucked and the request is working with postman but fails for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Let say, the object name here is Obj, then you can access the images src by

`Obj.images[0].src`

Comment: and how i can append this is in form data , like formdata.append("image",Obj.images[0].src)?  Is this right way if not can you please suggest the right way

Answer (score 0):

This is you can proceed:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', Obj.images[0].src);
this.$axios.post('/v1/candidate/attachment',formData)
    .then((objResponse) => {
                   
    },
    (objError) => {
                    
 });
```

Comment: This look sfine to me, is there any problem with that code? Although, I'll suggest you to use axios interceptors to pass your token.

Comment: no there is nothing wrong with the code but i am not able to add images with this post request i am getting exception like {exception : "param is missing or the value is empty:image"}

Comment: You might be receiving an array named "image" with parameter "attachment" inside it as you have used "image[attachment]".

Comment: are you talking about the json object ?

Comment: like while  doing this post request using postman everything is good but getting error while doing the same thing with script

Comment: Can you please look into server side what parameters are you receiving. Just console the same to look into it.

Comment: I solved the problem by first downloading that image to my local system and passing its path                                                                  data.append('image[attachment]', fs.createReadStream('/home/images/riceBasm.jpeg'));